# Closed normal subgroup of a rational free topological group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a pointed connected CW-complex and $F_{\ast}(X)$ is the (reduced) free topological group generated by $X$, in particular $F_{\ast}(X)$ is homotopy equivalent to $ \Omega \Sigma X$ as a topological space. Let consider $N$ to be a connected normal closed subgroup of $F_{\ast}(X)$ such that:

1. There exists an embedding of topological groups $h: F_{\ast}(X)\rightarrow N$ ($h$ is homomorphism of topological groups).
2. The integral homology $H_{i}(X,\mathbf{Z})$ is a rational vector space for any $i>0.$

Is it reasonable to hope that $H_{i}(N,\mathbf{Z})$ is a rational vector space for any $i>0 $ where $N$ is seen as an ordinary topological space ?

Comment: I have undeleted this question which you have deleted in the year before last year. -- Please do not self-delete your useful questions!